# urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)

Tags: get, python-requests-html

I am a new Python learner. When I tried the following code:

```
x = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
```

I get

```
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProxyError: ('Unable to connect to proxy', SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)')))
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)'))))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 513, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)'))))
>>> x = requests.get('https://www.baidu.com')
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)
```

Could anyone help with this? Thanks a lot!

I tried to install

```
pip install ndg-httpsclient

pip install pyopenssl

pip install pyasn1
```

But my SLS error is still not removed.